# How to redifine glm matrix variable or remove its transform?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I need to make several models one after another without using for loop. I define first one with `glm::mat4 model(1)`, make some translations and rotations on it, and then I want to remove all of its transform. But making it equal NULL doesn't work. Is there some function in glm I can call?

Also an additional question can somebody explain why I need to add "(1)" when declaring glm matrix variables. It doesn't work without it. Do I need to add something also when declaring glm matrix arrays, `glm::mat4 models[]`? Because the arrays don't seem to store variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default constructor of [`glm::mat4`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00701.html#ga0db98d836c5549d31cf64ecd043b7af7) doesn't initialize the matrix, it leaves the fields of the matrix uninitialize.

The [glm API documentation](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/index.html) refers to [The OpenGL Shading Language specification 4.20](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.20.pdf).

> **5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors**
>
> If there is a single scalar parameter to a vector constructor, it is used to initialize all components of the constructed vector to that scalar’s value. **If there is a single scalar parameter to a matrix constructor, it is used to initialize all the components on the matrix’s diagonal, with the remaining components initialized to 0.0.**

This means, to initialize a matrix by the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix), the constructor with a single scalar has to be used:

```
glm::mat4 model(1.0f);
```

and of course the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) can be assigned to an existing matrix:

```
model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
```

A dynamic array of e.g. 100 identity matrices can be generated by [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) with ease:

```
std::vector<glm::mat4> models(100, glm::mat4(1.0f));
```

Comment: I understand thanks! But when using model variable to draw several objects one after another in render loop, how do I clean first one's transformations before I draw the second one? I can't redifine glm::mat4 model(1) to restore it. Is there some other away?

Comment: @JohnSmith `model = glm::mat4(1.0f); `

Comment: It doesn't allow me to redefine the variable.

Comment: @JohnSmith Not without the type declaration not `glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);`, just `model = glm::mat4(1.0f);`

Comment: Okay thanks I understand. I can redefine it if I use a loop to render through the objects, so I'll do that then.